# How to use only the variable name from another file?

Tags: perl

I want to use only the variable name from the another file.

**test1.pl**

```
use warnings;
use strict;
our $name = "hello world";
print "Helllloo\n";
```

**test2.pl**

```
use warnings;
use strict;
require "test.pl";
our $name;
print "$name\n";
```

`test1.pl` contain some content with many functions. I used the variable `$name` from the test1.pl. But Don't run `test1.pl` while running the `test2.pl`. For example when run the `test2.pl` it result was

```
Helllloo   
hello world
```

That the `Helllloo` print from the `test1.pl`. How can use the another file variable name only How can i do it?

Comment: Where is the `file1.pl` and `file2.pl`?

Comment: @serensat  sorry see my edit

Comment: If you don't want the code in test1.pl to be run, move it to a subroutine.

Comment: This is a hack and you shouldn't be coding it like that. You should get *both* programs to `use` a config module that sets up values — preferably constants rather than global variables — and exports them using `Exporter`

Answer (score 3):

You should rewrite both `test1.pl` and `test2.pl` to `use MyConfig`, like this

**test2.pl**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use MyConfig 'NAME';

print NAME, "\n";
```

**MyConfig.pm**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package MyConfig;

use Exporter 'import';
our @EXPORT_OK = qw/ NAME /;

use constant NAME => "hello world";

1;
```

**output**

```
hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Const::Fast](https://metacpan.org/pod/Const::Fast) to export variables from a module:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use My::Config '$NAME';

print "$NAME\n";
```

In `My/Config.pm`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package My::Config;

use Exporter 'import';
our @EXPORT = ();
our @EXPORT_OK = qw{ $NAME };

use Const::Fast;

const our $NAME => "hello world";
__PACKAGE__;
__END__
```